# C# Override OnActionExecutingAsync Web API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement some logging around my web api calls. Nothing too fancy, but I'm still learning async/await and would like the logging to happen without disrupting performance.

Here's an example of what I'd like to implement, just not totally sure how to do it.

```
public class Logging : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // DoLoggingHere();   ????
        base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        // OrDoLoggingHere();  ????

        // Also, what does the return look like if any?
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // This method should/could complete before the logging completes.
        base.OnActionExecutedAsync(actionExecutedContext, cancellationToken);

        // Might log here too.
    }
}
```

Basically I don't want any of my logging to get in the way of the HTTP call. It should be transparent.

Looking for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and When to use \`async\` and \`await\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Answer (score 2):

You can await the call, so that thread is returned to pool for more incoming requests and then do logging after the call completes:

```
var result = await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
// logging code here

return result;
```

Comment: Could base.OnActionExecutedAsync() be called before my logging finishes?

Comment: your logging will be done after OnActionExecuting returns some result back, as we are awaiting it, and yes it will complete before OnActionExecuted gets called

Comment: I'm asking for the opposite. I would like to see OnActionExecuted be called first, then my logging.

Comment: then you have to await ``base.OnActionExecuted`` and after that logging code to be executed

Comment: await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
returns a void, cannot get the result like this var result = ...